# GoogleMaps v3 autocomplete.getBounds() returns undefined after being set

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete, coffeescript

I'm having an issue trying to bias the results of an Google Maps autocomplete to the last pin placed on a map. I'm following the Google's tutorial here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#change_search_area

My CoffeeScript code is as follows:

```
initSearch = ->
  autocomplete = new (google.maps.places.Autocomplete)(document.getElementById('location-query'), types: [ 'geocode' ])
  autocomplete.addListener 'place_changed', ->
    place = autocomplete.getPlace()
    addDestination(place, map, insertIndex) #places pin on map

    console.log 'autocomplete bounds (before): ' + autocomplete.getBounds()
    #setting bounds around new place
    biasCircle = new google.maps.Circle
      center: place.geometry.location
      radius: 500 #in kilometers

    autocomplete.setBounds(biasCircle.getBounds())
    console.log 'autocomplete bounds (after): ' + autocomplete.getBounds()
```

Which compiles into the following javascript:

```
initSearch = function() {
    var autocomplete;
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('location-query'), {
      types: ['geocode']
    });
    return autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
      var biasCircle;
      place = autocomplete.getPlace();
      addDestination(place, map, insertIndex);

      console.log('autocomplete bounds (before): ' + autocomplete.getBounds());
      biasCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: place.geometry.location,
        radius: 500
      });
      autocomplete.setBounds(biasCircle.getBounds());
      return console.log('autocomplete bounds (after): ' + autocomplete.getBounds());
    });
  };
```

The pin is correctly placed on the map, but no matter how many places I add, the console.logs always return:

```
autocomplete bounds (before): undefined
autocomplete bounds (after): ((9.923577823579402, -84.09528446042509), (9.932560976420598, -84.08616473957488))
```

The bounds are correctly being set (as shown by the second `console.log`), but results aren't actually being biased and the first one always results in undefined.

The test case we are using to test if the results are being biased are:
 1. Type 'San Jose' in autocomplete (top results should be in America)
 2. Add 'Limon, Costa Rica' as a marker on the map
 3. Type 'San Jose' in autocomplete, top result should be San Jose, COSTA RICA

We thought it might be an issue of scoping, so we tried `window.autocomplete` everywhere and still had the same issue. We also tried setting the autocomplete bounds in a separate method (instead of the place_changed event, but this also didn't work).

Thank you in advance for your help!

**Update: Trying Cedric's Answer**
On Cedric's advice, I'm trying to set the bounds outside of the listener callback (method is called from within listener), but I'm still getting the same issue. New code:

```
#Sets autocomplete bias
setAutocompleteBias = (place) ->
  console.log 'autocomplete bounds (before): ' + window.autocomplete.getBounds()
  #setting bounds around new place
  biasCircle = new google.maps.Circle
    center: place.geometry.location
    radius: 500 #in kilometers

  window.autocomplete.setBounds(biasCircle.getBounds())
  console.log 'autocomplete bounds (after): ' + window.autocomplete.getBounds()

window.autocomplete = null
#Autocomplete search box initialization
initSearch = ->
  window.autocomplete = new (google.maps.places.Autocomplete)(document.getElementById('location-query'), types: [ 'geocode' ])
  #autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map)
  window.autocomplete.addListener 'place_changed', ->
    place = window.autocomplete.getPlace()

    addDestination(place, map, insertIndex)

    setAutocompleteBias(place)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appear your autocomplete lacks required initialization of bounds either from the map

```
initSearch = ->
  autocomplete = new (google.maps.places.Autocomplete(                  
    document.getElementById('location-query'), types: [ 'geocode' ])
  autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map)
  autocomplete.addListener 'place_changed', ->
    place = autocomplete.getPlace()
    addDestination(place, map, insertIndex) #places pin on map

    console.log 'autocomplete bounds (before): ' + autocomplete.getBounds()
    #setting bounds around new place
    biasCircle = new google.maps.Circle
      center: place.geometry.location
      radius: 500 #in kilometers
    autocomplete.setBounds(biasCircle.getBounds())
    console.log 'autocomplete bounds (after): ' + autocomplete.getBounds()
```

or via a specific location

```
var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
  new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8902, 151.1759),
  new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8474, 151.2631));

var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
var options = {
  bounds: defaultBounds,
  types: ['establishment']
};
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```

Link from your tutorial https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#add_autocomplete

Link from documentation https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete

Comment: Great! I was able to get your first solution, `autocomplete.bindTo` working. However, this binds the maps current viewport, and trying to bind it to the LAST pin the user placed on the map. Your second solution always sets the first `console.log` to the defaultBounds. How can I set the bounds to the biasCircle after every time the place changed?

Comment: Not 100% sure to get your point; if you set the default bounds, we agree that you need to make it from outside the listener callback otherwise, it would always overwrite the user input. 
Other than that, when you set the bounds from the biasCircle, there is nothing wrong I can see.

Comment: Edited my question to include my current code. I'm tried setting the bounds outside of the listener callback, but I'm getting my original error (undefined with each first call).